# Replication with Global Transaction Identifiers across different MySQL versions

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a master MySQL server running 5.0.67. Would it be possible to configure a GTIDs replication as a slave that runs 5.7.17 that connects to this master? I have tried the traditional binary log position replication and have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

GTID was implemented as feature of MySQL 5.6, so short answer for 5.0.67 <-> 5.7.17 - NO

Long answer - even if 2 minor different versions support GTID, better and correct from points of view - have same versions for all servers in network, it help made Your life much more easy.